# Unable to launch /private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/

Tags: ios, swift, crash, ios12, xcode10beta3

I've been trying to test an app on an iOS 12 device, but every time I build it, it successfully builds on the device (my iPhone or iPad) but crashes and I receive this message:

Unable to launch /private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/

(I'm using Xcode 10 beta 3 and Swift 4.2)

[image: screenshot of error message]

Answer (score 12):

Check if you already trusted the author of the app in your development device:

Settings -> General -> Profiles & Device Management -> Company name -> Trust the app if not done yet.

I hope this helps

Comment: Thank you. But I ended up purchasing an Apple developer membership and testing apps via TestFlight. And realised my first app: https://itunes.apple.com/gb/app/ski-map/id1437116070?mt=8

Comment: That could also be a solution. But please, it would be helpful if you add in your question that you don't had a Developer's membership.

Comment: I didn’t have one when I asked

Comment: I know @JosephCatley, but others that want to help you don't know. Normally, if you develop iOS app you can't do it without a  Developer's membership, so we all assume here that you do have. Anyway, glad you solved your problem, but keep in mind to add as much info as possible to your question. We are all here to help each other :)

Answer (score 1):

I might have found a solution for you.

After deleting and renewing all Apple certificates which was not effective, I clicked on "system" tab in keychain access and changed Apple Worldwide Developer Relations Certification Authority from "always approved" to "default" setting.

Built again in xcode and it now runs properly.

Hope this helps!

Comment: I cannot believe it, this worked for me! Thanks, saved my day

Answer (score 0):

1- Check if you are using distribution profile while running the application directly from Xcode to device, if so please use developer profile instead.

2- Check if your device iOS is higher than the beta 3 as you are using Xcode10 beta3. If higher, try to use same Xcode beta version as your iOS

If thats not the case provide more info about the Build setting you are using.