# Unable to launch /private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/.app

Tags: ios, react-native, xcode10

I'm developing a react-native app for iOS and tried to build and run it on a new iPhone X (that I added to my apple developers account).

The app is crashing on launch with this alert popping on Xcode10: "Unable to launch /private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/"

Please note that the app is perfectly running on the iOS Simulator.

Also note that I carefully went through the following procedures without any success:

- [Unable to launch /private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51635230/unable-to-launch-private-var-containers-bundle-application)
- [Unable to launch /private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51635230/unable-to-launch-private-var-containers-bundle-application)

Do you guys have any idea what's going wrong???

Many thanks

Comment: maybe try to reset the code signing in order to refresh

Comment: @m1sh0 did it and it says now that my device has denied the launch request. any clue?

Comment: delete the app from the phone and run it again

Comment: @m1sh0 done sooo many times. Keep on telling me that my device had denied the launch. It is working without any problems on the iOS Simulator. So I'm guessing it is "code signing" related but I can't find it.

Comment: Last options t that I can suggest you is to restart the phone and re plug it in the computer. Make sure that you allow connection to the computer. And maybe restart the computer to be sure that there is no hung build process somewhere.

Comment: @m1sh0 and that's not it :-(

Comment: Sorry I try it at least you change the error and now you can google for different stuff. Like this one https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45421179/xcode-9-error-iphone-has-denied-the-launch-request

Comment: Yes thanks for trying. I was looking at it and not finding any piece of solution. I guess I'll throw my Mac and iPhone by the window...

Comment: @m1sh0 Found my solution. It was code signing related but at a system level. In Keychain Access, clicked on "system" tab and changed Apple Worldwide Developer Relations Certification Authority from "always approved" to "default". Build and run went through.

Answer (score 3):

After deleting and renewing all Apple certificates which was not effective, I clicked on "system" tab in Keychain Access and switched Apple Worldwide Developer Relations Certification Authority from "always approved" to "default" setting.

Built again in xcode and it now runs properly.

Hope this helps!

Might be related to Xcode10 update (I ran 9.4 while i first created my app) which either changed my Certification Authority setting or changed the way it handles "always approved" parameter.

Comment: @onzinsky Glad I could help!

Comment: I have Xcode 10.2 and I changed both these two 'keychain access' to default then it worked