# ios development: Unable to launch /private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/

Tags: swift, iphone, xcode

I am trying to test my app on my iPhone but it fails to launch the app and the error message "Unable to launch /private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/" keeps coming up. This happens to other apps that I have made.
I have tried all the methods proposed on the internet but none of them worked.
I haven't signed up to the apple developer. Can anyone please help me with this problem?

Comment: You can get a free developer account from Apple. This [post](https://9to5mac.com/2016/03/27/how-to-create-free-apple-developer-account-sideload-apps/) is a little old, but it should help you get started. Then you can deploy apps to your personal devices.

Answer (score -1):

Please see this answer, it worked for me: 
https://stackoverflow.com/a/53266043/9093967

> After deleting and renewing all Apple certificates which was not
>   effective, I clicked on "system" tab in keychain access and changed
>   Apple Worldwide Developer Relations Certification Authority from
>   "always approved" to "default" setting.
>
> Built again in xcode and it nows run properly.
>
> Hope this helps!